# How to solve Lumberjack quiz problem in prolog?

Tags: tree, prolog

I've read about this problem in the book Olympiads in Informatics. I managed to solve it in haskell, but I want recode it, but I realized it's hard to transform in prolog due to too many built in function usage (and I used many of them in declarative form). So I want to rebuild it from scratch and I tried to search for similar problems solved in prolog, but I did not succeed. Can somebody help me with linking a solution of a similar problem in prolog or expand my cut predicate. Huge thanks in advance.

The problem: "The task can be summarized in the following way: there
is a line of trees, with one meter of space between each of them. Each tree has a known
height, in meters, and you can cut it aiming it toward its right or left. When an "m" meter
tree falls, like in a domino game it forces the falling of its m−1 close trees, and this in
turn can force other tree to fall. You can decide which tree to cut, and for each of them
you can choose in which direction it will fall. Provide a list as short as possible of the trees to be felled, with a positive number representing a decision to the right and a negative number representing the code for a decision to the left.

[image]

My input:

```
tree(1,1).
tree(2,1).
tree(3,1).
tree(4,2).
tree(5,5).
tree(6,1).
```

My current code:

```
treecut(F, DL):-
    see(F),
    readfromfile([_|L]),
    seen,
    modifytolist(L, AL),
    cut(AL, DL). %how to do it?

readfromfile([Line|L]):-
    read(Line),
    Line \= end_of_file,
    readfromfile(L),
    !.
readfromfile([]).

modifytolist([], []):-!.
modifytolist([H|T], [H2|T2]):-
    pattern(H, H2),
    modifytolist(T,T2).

pattern(tree(P,H), (P,H)).

splitree((P,H), P, H):-!.
```

Output what I want

```
treecut('input1.pl',L).
L = [(5, -1),  (6, 1)].
```

Comment: was this some kind of contest?

Comment: Kind of. There were 9 different quiz problems and it was optional solving the problem. Meanwhile I solved it in a totally different way, if i'll be graded I will upload my solution too, it's a little bit different from above mentioned conditions but the basics are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This puzzle seems a lot of fun. Here is my first attempt:

```
makeZerosLeft([], [], _, 0) .
makeZerosLeft([I|In], [O|Out], N, Cnt):-
    makeZerosLeft(In, Out, N, Cnt1),
    Cnt is Cnt1+1,
    ( Cnt1<N ->   O=0 ;   O=I).

makeZerosRight(IO, IO, 0):- !.
makeZerosRight([], [], _):- !.
makeZerosRight([_|I], [0|O], N):-
    NN is N-1,
    makeZerosRight(I, O, NN).

checkZeros([]).
checkZeros([0|T]):-
    checkZeros(T).

fallingtrees(L1, L2, -1, N, O, L2):-
    makeZerosLeft(L1, O, N, _).
fallingtrees(L1, L2, 1, N, L1, O):-
    makeZerosRight(L2, O, N).

cutthem(L,[],0):-
    checkZeros(L).
cutthem(List, [(Pos,Dir)|CutList], s(S)):-
    append(L1,[Tree|L2],List), % choose Tree T
    Tree > 0, % not chopped
    length([_|L1], Pos), % pos of T 
    fallingtrees(L1, L2, Dir, Tree, O1, O2),
    append(O1,[0|O2], NewList),
    cutthem(NewList, CutList, S).
  
cutthemN(L, C, N):-
    cutthem(L, C, N).
cutthemN(L, C, N):-
    cutthemN(L, C, s(N)).

treecut(L,C):-
    cutthemN(L, C, s(0)).
```

Results:

```
?- treecut([1,1,1,2,5,1],L).
L = [(5, -1),  (6, -1)] ;
L = [(5, -1),  (6, 1)] ;
L = [(6, 1),  (5, -1)] ;
L = [(1, -1),  (2, 1),  (4, 1)] ;
...

?- treecut([2,3,2,1,4,2,1],L).
L = [(5,-1), (6,1)]  ;
L = [(5, -1),  (7, -1)] ;
L = [(6, 1),  (5, -1)] ;
L = [(7, -1),  (5, -1)] ;
L = [(1, -1),  (2, 1),  (6, 1)] ;
...

?- treecut([3,1,2,1,1,3,4,1,1,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,7,1,2,3],L).
L = [(1, 1),  (5, -1),  (6, 1),  (17, -1),  (20, -1)] ;
L = [(1, 1),  (5, -1),  (17, -1),  (6, 1),  (20, -1)] ;
L = [(1, 1),  (5, -1),  (17, -1),  (20, -1),  (6, 1)] ;
L = [(1, 1),  (5, 1),  (7, 1),  (17, -1),  (20, -1)] ;
L = [(1, 1),  (5, 1),  (17, -1),  (7, 1),  (20, -1)] ;
L = [(1, 1),  (5, 1),  (17, -1),  (20, -1),  (7, 1)] ;
...
```

My approach works directly on inputlists.
The heart of is the predicate `cutthem/3` which gets a List of tree-heights and and a search depth and will "output" the list of steps.
At first it checks if all trees were chopped (List contains 0's only). If so the job is done.
Otherwise it will choose a tree and the two lists of trees left and right from it (`L1` and `L2`). The tree has the height `Tree` and position `Pos`. Then it will choose a direction `Dir`. For a left fall it will replace the last `Tree` elements from `L1` with zeros (`O1`), for a right fall it will replace the first `Tree` elements from `L2` with zeros (`O2`). Afterwards it will create the new list from `O1` and `O2` with a zero in the middle and call itself again. A counter `S` is running to restrict the search-depth.
The search-depth is determined incrementally trough the predicate `cutthemN/3` so the algorithm is implemented as a Breadth-first search.

Comment: Hello. First of all thank you so much for this implementation. I tested for a bigger input (treecut([3,1,2,1,1,3,4,1,1,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,7,1,2,3],L)) and it works correctly but quite slow, but I learned a lot from it. If you don't mind I leave the question open for a few days for those who also want to solve it, maybe we can see some other faster implementations.

Comment: ^^ sure. I may be come up with something different since - as you already stated - it's a lot of code.

Comment: I reduced the code a bit more. Now the stepcounter works with the successor predicate s/1.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it, now it works properly with bigger inputs too :)